# Is it possible to use a "TypedQuery" as the DataSource of a JasperReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm creating a report with iReport that uses a [`JPQL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language) as DataSource

But there's one thing I don't seem able to do. I can only get the query to work if the fields I'm searching are known to Java by default, like on this example:

```
SELECT p.name FROM Person p
```

In this case I map `p.name` to `java.lang.String`

```
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[COLUMN_1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

and voilà, it all works.

But if I do a query like this:

```
SELECT p FROM Person p
```

And map `p` to `com.myproject.Person`,

```
<field name="person" class="com.myproject.Person">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[COLUMN_1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

I get an exception like this:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myproject.Person cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

That tells me that it can´t *cast* a `Person` to an array of `java.lang.Object` when I actually wanted the result to be a list of `Person`

Is there any way I can run this second query? Any place where I can set the type of the result?

I have already exported a `.jar` file of my project, and added it to iReport's *classpath*, it works because on the reports I send a list of objects as the DataSource, I can use and reference my classes just fine, but with `JPQL` it's giving me trouble

Has anyone ever done this? Or know how it's done?

Comment: The SQL `SELECT p FROM Person p` is saying select the column `p` from the table `Person` with an alias `p`. There is no field `person`. Java doesn't just cast rows from your database table to your custom class.

Comment: So you're saying that if I put `person` on my query it'll all work fine?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I tried what you said, and I still had the same result. the same name used in the query was used in the `field` tag

Comment: No, what I mean is that java won't convert a row from a table to the fields of a Class instance. Use your `<field>` elements with class types accepted by iReport, like String, Date, and the primitive types (those compatible with jdbc). Don't make them custom types.

Comment: But that is what I stated in the question. What I'd like to know is if a way to use custom classes exists.

Comment: There's probably something you can do by writing your own mapping logic from database table to java class, but you won't be able to do it with iReport tools.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Well, that's pretty much what I thought, but I just wanted to confirm it. Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis